# How can I determine whether an Android project was made using Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse

If the project is lacking gradle files, is it safe to assume it was made using Eclipse ADT?

Comment: If project contains gradle then its a Android Studio project if not its a eclipse project

Comment: yes it might be and import that project to android studio it gives you instruction about how to configure eclipse to android studio

Answer (score 1):

If the project contains `.settings` folder, `.project` file then it is clear indication that project was made using ADT. 
If the project contains `*.iml` file, `.idea` folder then it is created using AS.